# how to send value from view to template in javascript backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery ajax post and when a user write and press enter in a textbox this ajax triggers then it fetches a value from backend and show the result in a `<pre>` html element. http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/2133/ obviuosly this jsfiddledoes not show anything because I sis not put the ajax post inside it.

I want this text value have a default value when I load the page. like "Enter your value:" but how can I send this value to the textbox which is in template? So what I want to do is to send this defult value from my view to template.

here is my view code when the user hit enter:

```
if(e.keyCode == 13) {

            var currentLine = $('#terminal').text();
            var inputData = $(e.currentTarget).val();

            $('#terminal').text(currentLine + "\r\n" + inputData + "\r\n");
            AjaxPost(inputData);

             }

        }
```

and this is how I render my template (textbox is inside this template)

```
 this.$el.html(this.cliTerminalTemplate());
```

and this is my template:

```
<div class="row" id="box">
  <div  class="large-12 columns" >
  <pre id="terminalPre" width="2">
    <code id="terminal" style="color: #fff; padding: 1em;" ></code>
  </pre>
  <input type="text" id="textInput" name="" border: none;" autofocus>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to input data from your view to your template, than it depends on your template framework, how this is done.
With underscore templates you could do this:
in your render method:

```
var template = _.template( window.Template, {content:this.content} );
```

in your template:

```
<code id='terminal' style='color: #fff; padding: 1em;' ><%= content %></code>
```

here is a full jsFiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/2145/)

You should now, that re-rendering the whole view is not very useful in this case. If you really look for something like that, then let me know and I will re-factor the example.

EDIT:

For scrollbar use CSS attribute `overflow:auto`. Note, that inline CSS is not good practice. You should define your CSS in a separate file. I also have updated the jsFiddle link. I didn't find a fast solution for autoscroll and it's late here in Germany now :D.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :) since you are expert in backbone, i really appreciate if you can answer to another question. after the added data reach to the end of <pre> element in your js fiddle, is it possible to make a scroll bar or a write a jquery that enables the first added data to disappear from the begining and the coming data appears at the end? since in your js fiddle when the <pre> element gets full the coming data does not appear. That is really I need .thank you :)

Comment: Hello again, thank you so much, what I am doing is making a terminal like command prompt jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/2149 my problem is that when the text box reach to the end of <pre> it disappears so in order to make it appear first I need to write something on the keyboard and then the textbox appears. So I need to trigger it by clicking other wise there is no checkbox! and it is not userfriendly!  but I want this text box to always be at the pre element and not disappear. I hope I could explain my problem to you clearly.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't follow your last explanations. But I think you are looking for a way to emulate desktop terminals behavior in browser, right? So, first you should look how a desktop terminal works (input-, output streams etc.) After that you should look, what HTML (in your case maybe HTML5 would be better) is offering you to solve your problem. You found the <pre> and <code> tag. And for text input there is the <input type="text"> field. That's a good starting point. Now you should create a new question with more specific informations, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I really need your help! you are right I am ooking for a way to emulate desktop terminals behavior in browser. can you at least add your code in http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/2149/ and see what I mean. suppose I add elements and textbox goes down like terminal and when textbox reach to the end of pre element it disappears and in order to active it I need to write something and then it starts to appaer. but I want this textbox to be always available for user input. like the blinking $ in real terminal and they do not disappear when reaches to end. ur help means alot to me

Comment: I think I need to trigger a scroll bar when textbox reaches to end! something like autoscoll bar. the scrollbar that I added with css was inefficient because textbox goes down and down and in order to find where textbox is we need to scrolldown the pre element. so the scrollbar does not go down automactically

Comment: Hope this helps: [jsFiddle terminal](http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/2155/). But also I think the comment section here on stackoverflow is not for asking new questions. So next time please create a new question. It would be easier to find for other people having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

(The `input` element appears to be broken.  Unless the templating engine does weird things with what should be `style` attributes.)

Aside form that, can you just add the value to the `input` element in the template?  Something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="Enter your value:" name="" border: none;" autofocus>
```

Or, since it's not really a "value" but just instructional text, it could be a placeholder instead:

```
<input type="text" id="textInput" placeholder="Enter your value:" name="" border: none;" autofocus>
```

If you can't or won't change the template, then external to the template you can just run some JavaScript code when the page loads to set its value:

```
$('#textInput').val('Enter your value:');
```

Or, for a placeholder:

```
$('#textInput').prop('placeholder', 'Enter your value:');
```

This code would just need to run after the `input` is added to the DOM.

Comment: thank you so much. your assumption was right because I should not change the template. but I do not know how to write a function for loading a page. should I do through an event or pass it from here: this.$el.html(this.cliTerminalTemplate());?

Comment: @user2766267: It looks like you might be using a framework or two with which I'm unfamiliar.  Aside from any frameworks, the end result should be an HTML page with JavaScript (both embedded and referenced).  By default, JavaScript will be executed as the page is rendered in the browser.  This JavaScript can be anywhere on that page.  If it's on the page before the text input, then you can wrap it in jQuery's `document.ready`: http://api.jquery.com/ready/